# Javascript - Do something during long touch, stop on touch end (Android)

Tags: javascript, android

What I'm trying to accomplish is an input number field that increases as long as a button is held on a touch screen, and stop incrementing whenever the button is released.

**HTML**

```
<button id="inc-val">+</button>
<input id="qty-bottom" value="1">
```

**Javascript**

```
var node = document.getElementById('inc-val');
var longpress = false;
var timer = null;
var longtarget = null;

var cancel = function (e) {

clearTimeout(timer);
clearInterval(increm);


};

var click = function (e) {
if (timer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    clearInterval(increm);
}

if (longpress) {
    return false;
}

document.getElementById('qty-bottom').value++;

};

var start = function (e) {
console.log(e);

if (e.type === "click" && e.button !== 0) {
    return;
}

longpress = false;

timer = setTimeout(function () {
    increm = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('qty-bottom').value++;
    }, 300);
}, 10);

return false;
};

node.addEventListener("mousedown", start);
node.addEventListener("touchstart", start);
node.addEventListener("click", click);
node.addEventListener("mouseup", cancel);
node.addEventListener("mouseout", cancel);
node.addEventListener("touchend", cancel);
node.addEventListener("touchleave", cancel);
node.addEventListener("touchcancel", cancel);
```

Works perfectly so far on a desktop, and on an iPhone in Safari. The issue I'm having is trying to get it to work on Android. On an Android device (in Chrome), whenever I let go of the + sign or drag my finger out of the button, it keeps incrementing endlessly.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s77vsLxp/

(Result page easier to use on an Android) 
https://jsfiddle.net/s77vsLxp/embedded/result/

My end goal is to get it so a single short press raises the value by 1, while holding raises the value by 1 every 300ms. Stumped on why this works on anything but Android.

Comment: Turn of the auto select because the auto select is by default alway on and when you long press the button just auto select the button text and it keeps incriminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like long-pressing in Chrome for Android causes both `mousedown` and `touchstart` to fire, which is causing `setInterval` to be called twice. One fix would be to put a guard around where you are calling `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, then set `timer` to null on cancel.

See https://jsfiddle.net/4je2n3e8/